# How to scale out Azure SQL at database level?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

By any chance is it possible to do the federation on two different databases and to use them as a single database using federation root database, so that I can scale them out? I know I can do the federation on different data tables within a database and easily scale them out. Or if you know any alternative for handling a multiple databases having more than 1TB of size, please do advise.

Comment: do you mean https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-scale-introduction/ ?

Comment: Are you referring to the old SQL Azure Federations feature from a few years back? If so, that's been retired.

Comment: Russell Young & David Makogon -  I know it's been retired. So wt's alternative option I have ? I have 1 TB of Azure SQL Databse and my concen is, how I can handle the SQL Database having more than 1 TB of Size, how I can scale it out in better way or how can I use multiple Data Base having 1 TB size with above mention limitation ???

Comment: Sharding? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-scale-shard-map-management/

Comment: Are you dealing with multiple tenants within that TB? If so, elastic scale database pools with tenantID as your sharding key.  If it's just one very large database, then you can try to move to a services-oriented architecture where each database is a silo of information.  Other than that, you may be moving past the designs for the Platform-as-a-Services model, and over to Infrastructure (meaning Virtual Machines).